# Exibir div em hover

Tags: html, css

Como exibir uma div, que terá um resumo sobre o filme (texto), e um botão para (VER MAIS) ao passar o mouse sobre uma imagem.

Exemplo:

```
<a href="#">IMAGEM</a>
```

Ao passar o mouse em cima desse link, aparecer uma div ao lado direito, com informações sobre esse filme.

Um exemplo do que estou falando, é o site da netflix ou telecine play.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Se você vai fazer este HTML o melhor é usar somente CSS.

Crie uma div para cada link e seu conteudo. Exemplo:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="">Ver mais</a>
    <div class="descricao">Este filme é excelente! Recomendado a todas as idades</div>
</div>
```

Aí você pode esconder a descrição com:

```
.descricao{
    display: none;
}
```

e depois pôr visivel quando o mouse fizer hover em `.item`:

```
.item:hover .descricao{
    display: block;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/54Mrr/)

Se quiser fazer o efeito de aparece/desaparecer com animações pode usar CSS transitions.
[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/54Mrr/1/)

Comment: Boa Sergio, assim não precisa usar Javascript :p

Comment: Acredito que com `visibility` ficaria mais elegante ;)

Comment: @Beterraba, é conforme o gosto :) Por isso adicionei o segundo exemplo ;)

Comment: Só é bom lembrar que isso não funciona em IE9 ou inferior. Pois ele não aceita pseudo-seletores quando não é o último seletor.

Comment: @GabrielGartz, verdade. Por curiosidade __[estive a ver estatisticas](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201101-201401)__ sobre IE9 e já só 3% parece usar.

Comment: @Sergio legal esse statcounter, eu não conhecia, é falei mais como fator informativo mesmo, não sei qual é o foco do site do usuário, mas na minha opinião pessoal deveriam abandonar a compatibilidade com browsers não modernos. Eu te dei +1 hehe, eu gostei da sua solução, só quis ajudar.

Comment: @GabrielGartz, sim, o seu comentário é acertado e bemvindo! Por isso também fiquei a pensar e fui procurar numeros frescos para mim próprio também :)

Answer (score 5):

Algo como o `.show` e `.hide` do jQuery resolvem esse problema:

JS:

```
$("div.conteudo > img").hover(function() {
    $(this).next(".divDoLadoDireito").show(); //hover in
}, function() {
    $(this).next(".divDoLadoDireito").hide(); //hover out
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="conteudo">
  <img src="images/imagem.jpg" />
  <div class="divDoLadoDireito hide">
      <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Na minha opnião, a melhor solucao foi a indicada pelo Sergio, podes obter o resultado desejado apenas com .css o jQuery e' sempre uma dependencia no teu codigo.